# How to run method with arguments in separate thread using Parallel Tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

here is sample of code for

```
private void MethodStarter()
{
Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Method1);
Task mySecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Method1);
}

private void Method1()
{
 // your code
}

private void Method2()
{
 // your code
}
```

i am looking for code snippet for Parallel Tasks by which i can do the callback and pass argument to function also. can anyone help.

Comment: Your code actually run in parallel, so your question?

Comment: @CuongLe, see my answer. I think he wants to call the functions with parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood your question right this might be the anwser:

```
private void MethodStarter()
{
    Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1(5));
    Task mySecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2("Hello"));
}

private void Method1(int someNumber)
{
     // your code
}

private void Method2(string someString)
{
     // your code
}
```

If you want to start all the threads at the same time you can use the example given by h1ghfive.

**UPDATE:**
An example with callback that should work but I haven't tested it.

```
private void MethodStarter()
{
    Action<int> callback = (value) => Console.WriteLine(value);
    Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method1(5, callback));
    Task mySecondTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Method2("Hello"));
}

private void Method1(int someNumber, Action<int> intCallback)
{
     // your code
     intCallback(100); // will call the call back function with the value of 100
}

private void Method2(string someString)
{
     // your code
}
```

You can alos look at [Continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321274.aspx) if you don't want to pass in callback functions.

Comment: i need also callback mechanism that when Method1() will be finish then another function will alter me with status. can u put some light.

Answer (score 3):

You should try something like this instead :

```
Parrallel.Invoke(
  () => Method1(yourString1),
  () => Method2(youString2));
```

Comment: arguments passed is at your convenience ofc :)

Comment: That is also a nice solution if you want to start all threads at the "same" time.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out, I missed to specify it in my answer

Comment: i need also callback mechanism that when Method1() will be finish then another function will alter me with status. can u put some light.

Comment: Mmmh, take a look at the Task class methods' : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx ; I suspect what you want here is methods like ContinueWith

Comment: See my updated answer, you don't actually need a to use `ContinueWith` (but it is an alternative). I would instead use an explicit callback if that is what you want by passing in a function to the method as argument.

Comment: @Thomas - "I need also callback " - then why isn't that part of the question?

Comment: @TomasJansson `Parallel.Invoke()` is even less “at the same time” than `StartNew()`. It tries to be efficient, and so if you give it many delegates, it will execute several of them on the same thread in series.

Comment: @svick, I am not sure I agree that it is "less at the same time". If it is faster to run two methods after each other on the same thread than it is to create two thread and run them on separate threads I would still consider them to be closer two each other than if you have two threads. Doing things is parallel/async is something you want to do to be more efficient and using the `Parallel.Invoke` might help you with that in an abstract way.